# Google authentication failure in android

Tags: android, authentication, google-play-services

I am trying to run  [Try Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start)  sample. I have added **google-services.json** into `/app` and **server_client_id** in strings.xml. But still I am getting the following error

```
04-20 12:29:31.787 14544-14544/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/SignInActivity: handleSignInResult:false
```

Can anyone tell me what is the actual problem? I have not changed anything on the code. I have configured the project-level and app-level gradles too.

Here is the full LogCat

```
04-20 13:12:29.560 15925-15955/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-20 13:12:29.610 15925-15955/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
04-20 13:12:29.610 15925-15955/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-20 13:12:29.840 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ade59df time:324063633
04-20 13:12:31.680 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-20 13:12:31.830 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.google.samples.quickstart.signin time:324065621
04-20 13:12:31.900 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
04-20 13:12:31.900 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
04-20 13:12:31.930 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
04-20 13:12:31.930 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
04-20 13:12:32.010 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/GoogleSignInApiImpl: getSavedSignInResultIfEligible
04-20 13:12:32.010 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/GoogleSignInApiImpl: trySilentSignIn
04-20 13:12:32.030 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
04-20 13:12:32.030 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
04-20 13:12:32.080 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
04-20 13:12:32.110 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
04-20 13:12:32.110 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
04-20 13:12:32.130 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
04-20 13:12:32.140 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
04-20 13:12:32.140 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
04-20 13:12:32.160 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
04-20 13:12:32.260 15925-15955/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb86c9a88 (ListView) with handle 0xb878aa58
04-20 13:12:32.270 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@83cefe4 time:324066065
04-20 13:12:32.550 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{14bd6f68 token=android.os.BinderProxy@ade59df {com.google.samples.quickstart.signin/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin.ChooserActivity}} show : false
04-20 13:12:33.230 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/SignInActivity: handleSignInResult:false
04-20 13:12:34.610 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-20 13:12:34.700 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.google.samples.quickstart.signin time:324068493
04-20 13:12:34.780 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
04-20 13:12:34.780 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8454400
04-20 13:12:34.780 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
04-20 13:12:34.780 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
04-20 13:12:34.780 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
04-20 13:12:34.800 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
04-20 13:12:34.830 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@148c4c67 time:324068628
04-20 13:12:34.840 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{3a106db9 token=android.os.BinderProxy@83cefe4 {com.google.samples.quickstart.signin/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin.SignInActivity}} show : true
04-20 13:12:34.840 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{108345fe token=android.os.BinderProxy@148c4c67 {com.google.samples.quickstart.signin/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}} show : true
04-20 13:12:35.810 15925-15954/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
04-20 13:12:36.130 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/SignInActivity: handleSignInResult:false
04-20 13:12:36.170 15925-15925/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@83cefe4 time:324069967
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you add `google-services.json` into `/app` directly by copy paste or use Android Studio Terminal ?

Comment: @PravalSharma by copy paste

Comment: See my answer I also do same mistake when I made app with google+ login. @codehub

Comment: Can you show your full logcat ?

Comment: @LipanGhosh I added the LogCat.

Comment: Although I am unable to debug this but you have asked a very good question so I am upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out, First don't copy and paste `google-services.json` into `/app` directory.
Go to the Terminal in Android Studio `(View->Tool Windows->Terminal)`

Use this command on Android Studio Terminal (For Windows)

`move "C:\yourdownload folder here\google-services.json" "app\"`

Do not forget to write path name in quotes, else it will give "The syntax of the command is incorrect." exception

Hope this will help you.

Comment: yes I did the same as you mentioned in your answer but it didn't work for me. I am using ubuntu and I copied the google-services.json and pasted it into /app through terminal. I think this does not make any change. The issue is something else.